# Seeing System Operations

Tags: 14.04, gnome, software-recommendation

I would like to have something like this to be at the back of my desktop.

[image]

At the right most of the desktop you can see the operations of the system and any other thing. How can I incooporate this in mine too?

Comment: The yellow text with system information is conky. See For http://www.tecmint.com/install-conky-in-ubuntu-debian-fedora/ and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/conky and http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/conky-manager-gui-for-managing-conky.html

Comment: Googling the image gives me [Azenis Theme Pack](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=108882), but I gather you're just looking for the indicators on the right?

Comment: Configuration of conky is complex and personal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the main question:

This is most likely realized with [conky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conky_%28software%29).

#### About conky

Conky is a system monitor for X originally based on the torsmo code.

#### Install

You can install conky from default repositories via:

```
sudo apt install conky-all
```

#### First steps

After having installed you can choose by manually creating a config file, search one from in the internet or use some third party app like Conky Manager (http://www.teejeetech.in/p/conky-manager.html) to get started.

Assuming you have a first config file named `conkyrc` in `~/.config/conkyrc`.

You could start conky with this particular config like this from a terminal

```
conky -c ~/.config/conkyrc
```

Detailed instructions about setting conky up can be found [in the Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky).

#### Getting ideas / inspiration

There are tons of pages discussing conky configurations and use cases, one possible starting point to get inspired and more ideas on what is possible can be found [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Conkyporn/).

Comment: Although I did not down vote the question, you are likely to get more down votes as is is little more then a link only answer. You are going to need to leave a comment or explain how to install and configure conky.

Comment: At least i have had some idea of what it is and am quite getting familiar to Linux .

Comment: @Mwalughabura: bodhi.zazen was refering to an older version of my post - which wasnt that detailed. But good to hear it helps now in the current state. Greetings